# ¿Cómo podría controlar una relación de uno o muchos tutores con sus respectiva relación de hijos menores de edad?

Tags: vba

excelente día.

Tengo un formulario donde llevo un proceso en el cual controlaba los datos de un beneficiario asignado por un trabajador fallecido, lo realizaba con un listbox los datos del tutor o representante legal y en otro listbox a sus respectivos hijos menores de edad.

El problema se presenta cuando un trabajador ha tenido varios matrimonios. Un ejemplo sería que una persona se haya casado 04 veces, el color amarillo corresponde a su primer matrimonio y un hijo, el color verde al 2do matrimonio y dos hijos más, el color naranja a su 3er matrimomio y una hija más, y finakmente su pareja actual con 3 hijos más.[image: Ejemplo mencionado]

Cualquier sugerencia o guía que puedan aportar será de gran ayuda; la intención es controlar ese registro de realaciones. ¿cuál elemento debería usar? arraylist, collections, classes, listview.

Con agradecimiento.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Cuando dices "controlar" ¿A qué te refieres?. En cualquier caso, tu información encaja mejor en base de datos y Excel **no es** un programa para bases de datos. Te recomiendo encarecidamente que te plantees otras alternativas, como Ms-Access, SQL o similar. Con Excel acabarás complicándote la vida si lo usas como bases de datos y a larga da más dolores de cabeza que alegrías.

Answer (score 0):

No te sería más fácil normalizar tu tabla, en cada calumna un pariente, claro tendrías más campos pero sería fácil de manipular que tenerlo de esa manera. Por tu profesión sabrás que parientes son los más comunes, esos podrías cargarlos. Si de todas formas necesitas tener la información de esa manera podrías usar tablas dinámicas pero tendrías que normalizar tu tabla.

De esa manera como esta la puedes hacer pero será más trabajoso y susceptible a errores.